# Get count of true in bool[,] F#

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, f#

I have a bool[,] in F# and I want to get the count of true 's present.  How can i do this without descending into imperative programming?

this is my current solution, which is really just c# written in f#.

```
let mutable x = 0
for cell in cells do
    if cell = true then x <- x + 1
x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
let x = cells |> Seq.cast |> Seq.filter id |> Seq.length
```

What it does is filters out `false` values (see [Seq.filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340367.aspx)), and then just counts what's left.

Comment: You don't need the type annotation, and the number of elements in a sequence is returned by `Seq.length`, so that's then `cells |> Seq.cast |> Seq.filter id |> Seq.length`

Comment: Hah, yeah, my bad not checking this properly before posting! Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: nice. so many things going on in such a short statement.  beautiful. thanks

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use a `seq` and then use `Seq.sumBy`

```
cells |> Seq.cast<_> |> Seq.sumBy (function |true -> 1 |false -> 0);;
```